# ScalaQuery and Play framework: Best practice for handling unassigned (AutoInc) primary keys

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scalaquery

I am using Play 2.0.2 with ScalaQuery 0.9.5.

I have the following simple model code:

```
case class Task(id: Long, name: String)

object Task extends Table[(Long, String)]("task") {

lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

def id = column[Long]("id", O PrimaryKey, O AutoInc)
def name = column[String]("name", O NotNull)

def create(task: Task) = database.withSession {
  implicit db: Session => {
    Task.name insert(task.name)
  }
}
```

And the following code for handling Form submission:

```
val taskForm: Form[Task] = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> nonEmptyText
  ) {
    (name) => Task(-1L, name)
  } {
    task => Some(task.name)
  }
)

def newTask = Action {
  implicit request =>
    taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all, errors)),
      task => {
        Task.create(task)
        Redirect(routes.Application.tasks())
      }
    )
}
```

A few questions:

1) Is there a better method for handling transient primary key values than passing in a constant? Something similar to Anorm's NotAssigned?

2) Would it be better to add "id" -> ignored(-1L) to the Form mapping and use the Task's extractor functions?

3) Should the case class rather be defined without an id field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `Task` has an id you should not use this class to represent a value which has no id (yet). Anyway, that’s usual that a created object contains different data than what was filled in a form (e.g. creation date, etc.) so **it usually does not make sense to use the same class** to represent values needed to create an object and the created object itself.

So you can either define another case class, e.g. `TaskForm` (which may eventually inherit from a common base of `Task`), or, in your case, just use a form yielding a `String` value:

```scala
// Task
case class Task(id: Long, name: String)

object Task extends Table[(Long, String)]("task") {
  lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

  def id = column[Long]("id", O PrimaryKey, O AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name", O NotNull)

  def create(name: String) = database.withSession { implicit db: Session =>
    Task.name insert(name)
  }
}


// Application
object Application extends Controller {
  val taskForm = Form("name" -> nonEmptyText)
  def newTask = Action { implicit request =>
    taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all, errors)),
      name => {
        Task.create(name)
        Redirect(routes.Application.tasks())
      }
    )
  }
}
```